# Why does my Webpack configuration not use the babel loader (correctly)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, babeljs, build-tools

I'm about to refactor the frontend part of a webapp and decided to introduce webpack and babel to allow for javascript modules without losing browser compatibility.

For some reason Webpack does not transpile the arrow function I've introduced in a test js file that i chose as an entry in the config. It just throws the function out.

***If I just use the (project local) babel over the cli and target the same "test.js" webpack touches it works just fine.***

**My webpack.config.prod.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    mode: "production",
    entry: {
        test: "./js/test.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                        }
                    }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'js'],
    }
}
```

**babel.config.json I added for good measure:**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": []
}
```

**My test.js:**

```
import jQuery from "jquery";

window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;

() => {
    console.log("HEYHO 123!");
    console.log("jquery is array?", jQuery.isArray([1,2,3]));
}

console.log("HEYA 456!")
console.log("jquery is array?", $.isArray([1,2,3]));
```

I can find "HEYA 456" in the (minified) output file, but "HEYHO 123!" is nowhere to be found.

What is going on here? I can't find the error in my configuration after spending hours researching and checking the documentation.

Comment: Have you `npm install`ed the babel preset-env module?

Comment: Have you tried adding a .babelrc to the root of your project? For example, mine looks like:
  
`{
    "presets": ["env"]
}`

Comment: Are you sure this is at all related to Babel? If you assign `window.foo = () => {` instead, does it all work? To me, this sounds like you're running Webpack with a `production` build and it is stripping out the function because it can never be run because it is never callable from anywhere.

Comment: @colecmc Yes, I have. I'll add the package.json to the question.

Comment: @loganfsmyth This was the Problem! Thank you so much. I've underestimated the code transformations webpack does aside from the loader. Sadly can't upvote comments yet, please someone else do it.